# use multiple cells value as criteria2 for AutoFilter in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I want to filter multiples dates `A1:A3` in a Date column `A4:A1000`. I did this manually with macro recording mode, [see pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNUmf.png). I got this code for **criteria2**    `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _ xlFilterValues,`**`Criteria2:=Array(2, "1/1/2021", 2, "12/25/2021", 2, "7/26/2021")`** Now, I want to pass `A1:A3` to Criteria2 in VBA for automation.

I found some helping articles from different websites and tried but failed. below is what I found and failed:

**Criteria1** `:= Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A2")), ","), ",")` This works if we use **criteria1**. and this works for two cells only. but this is useless for my purpose.

I want to pass `A1:A3` to Criteria2 in VBA. **`Criteria2:=A1:A3`**. and I may vary number of cells in future for example **`Criteria2:=A1:A10`** instead of **`Criteria2:=A1:A3`**

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a date criteria for Criteria2, you must include the date hierarchy level.  The level enumeration is:

```
0 = year
1 = month
2 = day
3 = hour
4 = minute
5 = second
```

So you need to construct an appropriate array.

One way to do that is with a Function:

```
Function dateFilter(rg As Range)
    Dim w, c As Range, i As Long

ReDim w(0 To rg.Count * 2 - 1)
i = -2
For Each c In rg
    Debug.Print c.Address
    i = i + 2
    w(i) = 2 'the level
    w(i + 1) = c 'the cell value
Next c

dateFilter = w
End Function
```

And then you might, in your criteria, use something like:

```
Criteria2:=dateFilter([A2:A5])
```

If you have a large number of these operations, it may be faster to generate the criteria after reading the range object into variant arrays (instead of accessing one cell at a time), but the programming becomes more complex.

Comment: Thanks its a very good solution. only one minor problem is that if any cell is empty in **[A2:A5]** then VBA gives error `run time error 1004: autofilter method  of range class failed.`

Comment: I made a little modification in function and its working perfect. Thanks for your solution.
`Function dateFilter(rg As Range)
    Dim w, c As Range, i As Long

ReDim w(0 To rg.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count * 2 - 1)
i = -2
For Each c In rg
    If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
    Debug.Print c.Address
    i = i + 2
    w(i) = 2 'the level
    w(i + 1) = c 'the cell value
    End If
Next c

dateFilter = w
End Function`

Comment: @User1991 I did not consider you might be using an empty cell in your criteria range. Glad you got it working. I might have done it differently, but your method should be effective also.  I'd appreciate it if you could **Accept** my answer (there should be a tick mark next to it to indicate that).